# Type erasure in streams

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, type-inference, type-erasure

I'm not newbie into Java 8, and I know streams are very powerful, convenient way to process data and I use them very often. In fact I was doing much more comlicated data processing with streams without any issue, but look at this? It looks like quite basic processing, yet there is a problem with type erasure. Why it can't handle such a data collection?

```
Set[] arrOfSets = {new TreeSet<>(List.of(1, 2)), new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, null))};

/*why type erasure wins here? */
List<Number> collect = (List<Number>) Arrays.stream(arrOfSets).flatMap(Set::Stream).collect(Collectors.toList());

Object collect2 = Arrays.stream(arrOfSets).flatMap(set -> set.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Collect2:" + collect2); /*[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, null]*/

/*Here type interference works fine*/
List<Integer> collect1 = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(collect2.getClass().getSimpleName()); //ArrayList
```

Same with `List<Set>`:

```
List<?> collect3 = listOfSets.stream().flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Runtime exception: java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.List**

I feel it's a streams' huge drawback. Any chances to improve type interference in Streams API in future sdk or there's no way to overcome that issue?

Comment: `Set[] arrOfSets` - you broke the type inference at this point already, what generic data type do the `Set`s contain? And you probably wanted to use `Set::stream` instead of `Set::Stream`, right?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a raw `Set[]` without a generic type.

To make your code work you should either use a generic array:

```
Set<Number>[] arrOfSets = new Set[]{
        new TreeSet<>(List.of(1, 2)), 
        new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, null))
};
List<Number> collect = Arrays.stream(arrOfSets) // Stream<Set<Number>>
        .flatMap(Set::stream) // Stream<Number>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or cast your Stream from `Stream<Object>` to `Stream<Number>` using `Stream.map()`:

```
Set[] arrOfSets = new Set[]{
        new TreeSet<>(List.of(1, 2)), 
        new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, null))
};
List<Number> collect = Arrays.stream(arrOfSets) // Stream<Set>
        .map(i -> (Set<Number>) i) // Stream<Set<Number>>
        .flatMap(Set::stream) // Stream<Object>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As you are already mentioned, the problem is the same for `List<Set>`. The `Set` has no type, so either use `List<Set<Number>>` or cast, like before. **I would recommend using typed `List`s or `Set`s.**

Comment: Anyway why it shouldn't be an array with `Set<? extends Number>[]`?

I mean TreeSet<Integer> isn't a subtype of `Set<Number>`

Comment: Yes you also can use `Set<? extends Number>[]` or `Set<Integer>[]`. All of them should work.

Comment: Yes, but actually why it works with Array `Set<Number>[]`. It should accept only sybtypes of `Set<Number>` and `TreeSet<Integer>` isn't a subtype of `Set<Number>`, so it should work only with Array `Set<? extends Number>[]`? How type erasure makes it work here?

Comment: The problem is that you can not create a generic array (e. g. `new Set<Integer>[]{...}` will throw a compile error) so you have an unchecked type cast in the first line. In that case you could also try to cast the array to `Set<YourClass>[] arrOfSets = new Set[]{...}` and the compile will not throw an error.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp your assumption that you are creating a `TreeSet<Integer>` is wrong. You have specified `new TreeSet<>(List.of(1, 2))` with the “diamond operator”, allowing the compiler to infer the type from the context, so it’s allowed to infer `Number` as the element type. E.g. `Set<Set<Number>> setOfSets = Set.of(new TreeSet<>(List.of(1, 2)), new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, null)));` works as well. But generally, Generics and arrays [don’t play together](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays); that’s how it always has been.

Comment: @Holger Yes I know that I create a `TreeSet<Number>` with `new TreeSet<>()` in this case. All I wanted to point out was that arrays and generics don't play together, like you said. Maybe my explanation was not that good.

Comment: @Holger not sure, if he's not right. It still works if you create `TreeSet<Integer>` explicitly, so TreeSet could be parametrized with Integer as well

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp my bad, I wanted to target `@Schroedinger` actually, regarding [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446863/type-erasure-in-streams/56447089?noredirect=1#comment99488676_56447089) but completion inserted your name (as both begin with S) and I didn’t look close enough.

Comment: so @Holger are you sure that TreeSet is parametrized with Number, not Integer? It works both for TreeSet<Integer> and with diamond operator TreeSet<> as well

Comment: @Schroedinger yes, he’s right regarding arrays and the missing type safety. I wanted to address your initial confusion. So you can write `Set<Set<Number>> setOfSets = Set.of(new TreeSet<>(List.of(1, 2)), new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, null)));` but not `Set<Set<Number>> setOfSets = Set.of(new TreeSet<Integer>(List.of(1, 2)), new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, null)));`. Whereas raw typed arrays accept anything. So the solution is not to use arrays for generic types, but `List.of(…)` or `Set.of(…)` or just `Stream.of(…)` when you’re going to stream over them anyway.

Comment: @Holger yes, you should use     `Set<Set<? extends Number>> setOfSets = Set.of(new TreeSet<Integer>(List.of(1, 2)), new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, null)));` instead

Comment: @Holger can you also address to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56447939/10849556

Comment: A `Set[]` is not a `Set<Object>[]`, that’s a sloppy statement. Just like a raw type `Set` is not a `Set<Object>`, not even a `Set<?>`. However, in case of arrays, all of them are problematic, due to the legacy covariance.